# Windows Phone 8.1 vs Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 - is there missing documentation on MSDN?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm attempting to port some .NET code to a Windows Phone 8.1 (not Silverlight) library and have been banging my head against the wall for a while now trying to understand why `System.Net.IPAddress` wasn't available.

According to the [Windows Phone MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Net.IPAddress(v=vs.105).aspx), it appears to be available for Windows Phone 8.1

```
Version Information: Windows Phone OS Supported in: 8.1, 8.0, 7.1

Platforms: Windows Phone
```

and the ["regular" MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.ipaddress) states

```
Version Information: 
.NET for Windows Phone apps
Supported in: Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Silverlight 8.1

Platforms: Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8,
```

Yet I cannot access `System.Net.IPAddress` in any Windows Phone 8.1 project. I can access it a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 project.

Am I misreading the documentation? Is there something extra I might need to reference in my Windows Phone 8.1 project?

(It's interesting that Windows Phone 8.1 app references `.NET for Windows Store apps` and `Windows Phone 8.1` and the Silverlight app references `.NET for Windows Phone` and `Windows Phone` so I'm sure the first has less accessible to it - it's just that I can't see that mentioned in the documentation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just look in the wrong place.
Windows Phone 8.1 is a Windows Runtime app, which is nothing to do with Windows Phone Silverlight, you must be oriented to Windows Store Apps API.

[System.Net for Windows Runtime apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454046.aspx)

For functional applications for the Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Store App should be the same, so you just can not tie anything from Windows Phone Silverlight to Windows Store App if they are not suitable

[Here](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/labs/difflists) you can look full list of differences.

Comment: Right; I see the new documentation referring to "Windows Phone [Store] 8.1" apps vs. "Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight" apps.