# MVVMCross - IBarCodeService registration in viewmodel

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, mvvmcross

Is there any interface to inject IBarCodeService in my viewmodel in MVVMCross? Like ISQLiteConnectionFactory for ISQLConnection.

If anyone knows, please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know MVVMCross, but I'm pretty sure you will have to use a dependency injection framework if you want to inject custom interface implementations. Where does your IBarCodeService comes from ?

Comment: How are you registering your types with the MvxApplication's IoC container? For example, in my `App.Initialize` I make a call to register all types ending with `Service`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. IBarCodeService is inbuilt in MVVMCross bar code plugin. I am trying to inject this service via constructor. This injection works with ISQLiteConnectionFactory and IMvxFileStore. The framework creates instances for these services but not for IBarCodeService

Comment: IBarCodeService is not a built in MvvmCross plugin.  It's an external plugin managed [here](https://github.com/aritchie/acrmvvmcross)

Comment: You can download the nugget by running this in your package manager:  Install-Package Acr.MvvmCross.Plugins.BarCodeScanner

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of ways you can do this... You can set up your own MvvmCross plugin which accomplishes this via a Bootstrap file.  As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788164/custom-plugin-in-mvvmcross) Stuart shows the user how to go about creating a plugin.

If you don't want to do the work of creating your own plugin you can also just take advantage of the InitializeLastChance routine in your Setup.cs in your iOS/Android project.  For instance my InitializeLastChance() looks like this:

```
    protected override void InitializeLastChance()
    {
        Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<ISecurePersistenceService, SecurePersistenceService>();
        base.InitializeLastChance();
    }
```

So for example I have a ISecurePersistenceService that I have defined in my core project that I use to encrypt sensitive data for my application.

In my core project I have a ISecurePersistenceService.cs and in my iOS project I have a SecurePersistenceService.cs which implements the interface.  With the addition of my code in the Setup.cs in my iOS project, MvvmCross now knows how to resolve

```
var securePersistenceService = Mvx.Resolve<ISecurePersistenceService>();
```

Or even use constructor injection like so:

```
private readonly ISecurePersistenceService persistenceService;

public MyViewModel(ISecurePersistenceService persistenceService)
{
    this.persistenceService = persistenceService
}
```

This is all possible because the MvvmCross is making use of its own [IoC implementation](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. The problem here is MVVMCross is not able to resolve IBarCodeService. When i execute         var scan = Mvx.Resolve<IBarCodeService>();, I get "Failed to resolve type Acr.MvvmCross.Plugins.BarCodeScanner.IBarCodeService" exception. Requirement in my project is to scan barcode using windows mobile 8.1 and it should be platform independent. The functionality should work in IOS and Android. MVVMCross bar code plugin is platform independent but not sure how to resolve IBarCodeService.

Comment: Verify you have the Acr.MvvmCross.Plugins.BarCodeScanner package installed in your Windows Phone 8.1 project.  Then verify you have a Bootstrap folder which holds BarCodeScannerPluginBootstrap.cs

Comment: Thank you very much for you response. I have this plugin installed in my project. But bootstrap file was missing in my project. I added it manually under Bootstrap folder and added the below code.            public class BarCodeScannerPluginBootstrap
        : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<Acr.MvvmCross.Plugins.BarCodeScanner.PluginLoader>
    {
    } ... but no luck. Getting exception. I get this bootstrap file by default, when i install plugin for sqlite or filestore. But i am not getting for barcode plugin. I have one small doubt , Doesn't this plugin support for windows phone 8.1?

Comment: If I look at the project here:https://github.com/aritchie/acrmvvmcross/tree/master/Acr.MvvmCross.Plugins.BarCodeScanner.WinPhone I do not see the plugin bootstrap set up.  You should be able to use the initialize last chance code I have above to load it manually.  Please post any exceptions you get trying this

Comment: Thanks for your response. This way of registration works in WP8.0. But  i get not implemented exception, when i call read method. In WP8.1, i am not able to register the plugin itself. I tried to load the plugin using below method in App.cs  public override void LoadPlugins(Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins.IMvxPluginManager pluginManager)
        {
            base.LoadPlugins(pluginManager);
            pluginManager.EnsurePlatformAdaptionLoaded<Acr.MvvmCross.Plugins.BarCodeScanner.PluginLoader>();
        }.   But i get "could not load assembly" exception.

Comment: I guess the implementation of this plugin is not completed.

Comment: Could be... I wonder if this could be due to the different kinds of win phone projects.  There's win phone silver light 8.1 and win phone 8.1.  Windows phone 8.1 is using the Windows store API I believe.  The plugin you are trying to use is for Windows phone 8.1 silver light.  See here for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170055/windows-phone-8-1-vs-windows-phone-silverlight-8-1-is-there-missing-documentat

Comment: Yes exactly. We have decided to use Zxing as of now for bar code scanning. This is platform specific plugin but we don't have any other option. Once complete mvvmcross bar code service plugin is released for windows phone 8.1, we will start using it.

Comment: At this point it is not a guarantee that a plugin will even be released.  Again, the plugin you are referencing is a third party plugin.  The beauty of open source is that you can fork Acr's repository and build the plugin yourself and give back to the community!

Comment: At last, i used ZXing bar code service and Lumia imaging SDK for camera capture. With these combination, the bar code scanning works fine.

Answer (score 0):

At last, i used ZXing bar code service and Lumia imaging SDK for camera capture. With these combination, the bar code scanning works fine.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Is it not an additional information - that's the answer. Read it carefully again. The OP has found the solution, and shared his experience with other users. The answer is poor...but that's another story.